# How can I get custom customer code from javascript in Magento 2?

Tags: customer, magento2.4, customer-attribute

I added a custom customer attribute to the eav_attribute table. I am trying to get this from within js.

For example, I can get

this.customer.firstname

but I can't get it like this

`this.customer.custom_customer_code`

How can I do that? Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a reference of `customerData` function in the below file and based on that you can create an after plugin for `getSectionData` and set the value for your custom attribute and that attribute value you will get in your JS file.

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/CustomerData/Customer.php
```

Reference Plugin:

```
   public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Customer $subject, $result)
        { 
$result['custom_attribute'] = 'test123'; //here you can set the customer attribute value from customer model object. 
return $result; 
}
```

I got the best reference for you. Please check and I am sure this will work. Please follow the steps.

https://popatkaran.wordpress.com/2018/07/02/magento-2-set-customer-data-in-local-store-to-load-properly-with-varnish-anywhere/

Please let me know if you need more details